# Filter tag not getting recognized in Struts 2

Tags: java, eclipse, struts2, filter, web.xml

I am trying to follow a [tutorial](http://javabrains.koushik.org/struts2.html). I am using Eclipse and Tomcat server to run the application.

My filter tag does not get recognized and the appropriate action file is not called. When I try to run the application

```
http://localhost:8080/Struts2Starter
```

it simply says `"The requested resource is not available"` .

I have downloaded the appropriate struts2 jar files and pointed them to `WEB-INF/lib`.

**I have my `web.xml` as follows:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>Struts2Starter</display-name>
  
    <filter>
      <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
      <filter-class>
         org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter
      </filter-class>
   </filter>

   <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
   </filter-mapping>

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  
 
</web-app>
```

**I have my `struts.xml` as follows which is in the classpath(src folder):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
    
    <struts>
    <package name="default" extends="struts-default">
    <action name="getTutorial" class="org.kowshik.action.TutorialAction">
     <result name="success">/success.jsp</result>
    </action>
   
    </package>
    
    </struts>
```

I am really not sure what I am missing.

Comment: is there any error during startup or at request time  ?

Comment: no..i do not get any error at all..

Comment: @Sruthi if you don't get any errors, then you are fine and resource is not available because there's no such resource. Either you let the struts handle the resource or web server. There's no other option available at the moment and you should know this.

Comment: What do you mean "the filter tag isn't recognized"? Yo uneed to set debug mode to true, set logging to debug, and watch the logs on startup.

Answer (score 0):

The class `org.kowshik.action.TutorialAction` is not recognized in the action configuration. You should check the name of the package that corresponds to the action class.

You have started your application from the root of your web content. That means if your root folder has an `index.jsp` it will be used by the web server regardless of struts filters it as you configured it in the `filter-mapping`. The most useful part of the content of this file is redirect to the full featured struts action. For example

```
<% response.sendRedirect("getTutorial.action"); %>
```

Also add this constant to the `struts.xml` if you accidentally put a convention plugin to your `WEB-INF/lib` folder:

```
<constant name="struts.convention.action.disableScanning" value="true" />
```

Comment: I have the class TutorialAction in my project in the corresponding package. I have an index.jsp in the root folder and it does not get called instead throws an exception The requested resource is not available whenever I include filter in web.xml..

Comment: Check the server logs that the application is started and it has the resource.